# Zend framework home page URL index issue after removing htaccess in zend 2.2

Tags: url, zend-framework2, zend-framework-routing

I want to run application without .htaccess and i removed same. Now when i click n home page e.g. 'localhost/testsite/index.php/' it works and related link url also also work properly. But when i try to open 'localhost/testsite/index.php' then it given below error message.

A 404 error occurred
Page not found.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.

No Exception available

Also when I open 'localhost/testsite/' the home page come properly but related link stop to work. My application module.config.php is given below.

```
return array(
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),   
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
'view_manager' => array(
    'display_not_found_reason' => true,
    'display_exceptions'       => true,
    'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
    'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
    'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
        'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
        'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
    ),
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        __DIR__ . '/../view',
    ),
),
```

);

Please help if anyone run application without htaccess in zend 2.2 .

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Generic route to make the slash optional, you can do this with the segment route type

```
/**
 * Generic Route
 */
'generic' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route'    => '[/:controller[/:action[/:id]]][/]', // allow trailing slash too [/]
        'constraints' => array(
            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
            'action'        => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'controller'    => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
            'id'            => '[0-9]+',
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Index',
            'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: I have put index.php, js, img and css in root folder of application. Application has been hosted on IIS and we are not using htaccess. Application is running with localhost/testsite/index.php/,localhost/testsite/ but not with localhost/testsite/index.php . Please help.

Answer (score 0):

the starting point of your ZF2 application is located in public/index.php which is not in the root folder of your publishing host, so we need .htaccess(uses mod_rewrite of apache) to redirect all your browser request to [/] to [public/index.php], if you have any other mechanism to simulate the redirect, you can bypass the .htaccess file.